# Emailing a .xap file and how to sign

Tags: vb.net-2010, xap

I am a newbie to windows app dev...mainly used vb.net 2010 for desktop applications.  I wanted to dabble and made a simple app and in the /bin/release directory there is my .xap file.

I do not own a windows phone so am using the emulator, but when I emailed the xap file to my friend, she got the message about cant install company app.

I believe this is all about signing the app but how can I just email the file without the need for a certificate?  Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to register a device as a developer device.
[This is free and pretty easy to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).